# Mongoose find All subdocuments satisfying a condition

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have the document GradePovider, containing elements :

```
{
"_id": ObjectId("568a466f2c48409006ab4862"),
"values": [
    {
        "_id": ObjectId("568a466f2c48409006ab4868"),
         "description": "has et delicata moderatius"
    },
    {

        "_id": ObjectId("568a466f2c48409006ab4867"),
        "description": "description two"
    },
    {

        "_id": ObjectId("fakeId"),
        "description": "description three"
    }
  ]
}
```

And I would like to do a search by list of value._id. 
so that I get in response of a search by  [ObjectId("568a466f2c48409006ab4868"), ObjectId("568a466f2c48409006ab4867")] :

```
 {
"_id": ObjectId("568a466f2c48409006ab4862"),
"values": [
    {
        "_id": ObjectId("568a466f2c48409006ab4868"),
         "description": "has et delicata moderatius"
    },
    {

        "_id": ObjectId("568a466f2c48409006ab4867"),
        "description": "description two"
    } 
  ]
}
```

I tried using this code:

```
gradeModel.GradeProvider.find({
        'values._id': {
          $in: node.grades
        }
      }, {
        "values.$": true
      }, function (err, gradeProviders) {}
```

This code returns only the first match of values, for each gradeProvider.
I guess I would need to use aggregation of this. I did not manage to get it right so far.

```
radeModel.GradeProvider.aggregate([{
        $match: {
          'values._id': {
            $in: node.grades
          }
        }
      }, {
        $project: {
          providerName: 1,
          values: 1
        }
      }], function (err, gradeProviders) {}
```

This code returns the right GradesProviders, but it returns all the values.

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

The following pipeline should work for you:

```
var pipeline = [
    {
        "$match": {
            "values._id": { "$in": node.grades }
        }
    },
    {
        "$project": {
            "providerName": 1,            
            "values": {
                "$setDifference": [
                    {
                        "$map": {
                            "input": "$values",
                            "as": "el",
                            "in": {
                                "$cond": [
                                    { 
                                        "$setIsSubset": [ 
                                            [ "$$el._id" ], 
                                            node.grades 
                                        ] 
                                    },
                                    "$$el",
                                    false
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    [false]
                ]
            }
        }
    }
];

gradeModel.GradeProvider.aggregate(pipeline, function (err, gradeProviders) {});
```

The operators that make a significant difference are the **[`$setDifference`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/setDifference/#exp._S_setDifference)** and **[`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/map/#exp._S_map)** operators. The **[`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/map/#exp._S_map)** operator in essence creates a new array field that holds values as a result of the evaluated logic in a subexpression to each element of an array. The **[`$setDifference`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/setDifference/#exp._S_setDifference)** operator then returns a set with elements that appear in the first set but not in the second set; i.e. performs a relative complement of the second set relative to the first. In this case it will return the final `values` array that has elements not related to the parent documents via the `_id` property, based on the conditional operator **[`$cond`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/#exp._S_cond)** which evaluates the expression returned by the operator **[`$setIsSubset`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setIsSubset/#exp._S_setIsSubset)**.

Comment: Yes, I have just one point
 "$setIsSubset": [ 
                                            [ "$$el._id" ], 
                                            node.grades 
                                        ] 
is not returning true for two identical ObjectId (but not the same instance).
Any idea how to manage this case ?
apart from applying toString on the array of ObjectId ?